# Log file says "Writing..."

Tags: java, logging, web-applications

My web application runs using `Tomcat 7`, `Windows Server 2008R2`, `Java`, `JSP`, `SQL Server 2012`

The .out log file has thousands of rows with just the words "writing...."

I used NotePad++ to search the entire application (including JARs etc.) for "Writing." and and nowhere can I find any code that is the culprit.

Although it does seem that .jar files are zip files - and thus this search wouldn't work as I am searching for plaintext (see comments on  [Fast way to update text in a Jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735374/fast-way-to-update-text-in-a-jar-file) ) when I edit the .jar files in NotePad++ they all seem to have plaintext in them such as `org/saxpath/XPathHandler.class`

I had the same problem when the application ran under Oracle and Oracle Application Server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Third party code that might be writing?

Comment: libraries used might write. check the jars from the project.

Comment: check the logger name which is printing it, if it is from any  third party jar than create a logger for that and provide log level error. so the low level log will not print from that logger.

Comment: Thanks for comments... I edited my question accordingly. @Naveen I am first interested in finding what is causing it...  and then I will think about whether I will try and get rid of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by the following in `web.xml`

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Compress</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.jspbook.GZIPFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Compress</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Compress</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```